# RxJS custom Observable doesn't fire if i move to separate function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

Currently i'm learning RxJS and i am on an awkward situation where i created a basic custom Observable to fetch from a backend service and then make some chaining using pipe.

I'm making this on React. On useEffect function inside App.js i have this code which is running:

```
const http$ = Observable.create(async observer => {
      try {
        const res = await axios("localhost:3001");
        await observer.next(res.data);
        await observer.complete();
      } catch (er) {
        observer.error(er);
      }
    });

    const posts$ = http$.pipe(
      map(posts => posts.map(post => ({ ...post, genre: "Music" })))
    );

    posts$.subscribe(
      posts => console.log(posts),
      noop,
      () => {
        console.log("completed");
      }
    );
```

Now when i go and move Observable functionality on a separate file and try to run again, it doesn't run for a weird case. It doesn't even make the request and no errors are shown on console.

function inside utils.js:

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { axios } from "axios";

export const createHttpObservable = url =>
  Observable.create(async observer => {
    try {
      const res = await axios(url);
      await observer.next(res.data);
      await observer.complete();
    } catch (er) {
      observer.error(er);
    }
  });
```

and inside App.js on some point:

```
 const http$ = createHttpObservable('localhost:3001');
 const posts$ = http$.pipe(...
```

Can someone help me on this? Because i think i'm missing something.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where are you subscribing to the observable in the 2nd case?

Comment: Inside App.js as i did in the first place. Didn't change any logic, just moved the Observable on separate function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i figured out that was a wrong import of axios library. Nothing wrong with current implementation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: At least add your solution if you answer your own question...